# Killing all python scripts except one python script and the grep process

Tags: linux, bash, python-2.7, shell, centos

How can I run command in bash to kill all python scripts except script called `test.py` and the grep's pid itself, in case we are using something like `ps -ef |grep`

I think I can use something like `pgrep` python to ignore the grep process, but how do I also exclude the `test.py` script? I know there is an option to do grep -v, is there option to do `pgrep -v`

Clarification: except grep process- means when we do for example `ps -ef |grep test1.py` we get also the grep pid that used to bring this result. I don't want to kill it as this process is no longer exist in the stage that results are shown.

**EDIT**:
I need this command to be valid through python's `subprocess` module
`k = subprocess.Popen('[some_bash_cmd_here]',shell=True)`
`k.wait()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pgrep -fl python` to get all the commands matching `python` then get it piped with `awk` to get the process id by excluding `test.py` from the commands and finally pipe it to `xargs kill`:

```
pgrep -fl python | awk '!/test\.py/{print $1}' | xargs kill
```

Comment: To get the arguments in more recent `pgrep`s don't you need to use `-fa` instead of `-fl`? At least with RHEL 7 that's the case, and with recent Fedora vintages too

Comment: Actually I don't know about latest `pgrep` as I am on OSX and have another `pkill` installed via `home brew` and they both don't support `-a`

Comment: Great thanks now I try to launch this script via gitlab-ci which can run python scripts.
In test.py I do the following you wrote in the following code:
`k = subprocess.Popen(bash_cmd,shell=True)  
k.wait()`

Comment: And I get return code -15, while launching the exact command manually on bash without python works like a charm, do you know what is the -15 return code for python subprocess, and  how can I fix it?

Comment: Return code `15` indicates single single #15 i.e. `SIGTERM`. You can check signal names with `kill -l` command in unix shell.

Comment: Can you please explain further what is "single single #15"?
And I think I got -15 as a returncode not 15 ( `k.returncode()`)
Thanks

Comment: That is indeed the signal number. If you change last `xargs` to `xargs kill -1` then return code will be `-1`

Answer (score 1):

A much better approach is to do the filtering in Python itself, where you can easily keep state etc.

```
import subprocess, os
for proc in subprocess.check_output(['ps', '-ef']).split('\n'):   # ps options depend on your OS
    if 'python' in proc and 'test.py' not in proc:
        os.kill(proc)
```

Answer (score 0):

Some modifications to anubhava and tripleee methods, using Python 3 and PID.

anubhava method (using the PID instead of the script name):

```
import os
from subprocess import Popen

pid = os.getpid()
command=f"pgrep -fl python | awk '!/{pid}/{{print $1}}' | xargs kill"
result = Popen(command, shell=True)
```

tripleee method (using PID):

```
import subprocess, os, signal

pid = os.getpid()
for proc in subprocess.check_output(['ps', '-ef']).decode().split('\n'):   # ps options depend on your OS
    if 'python' in proc:
        current_pid = int(proc.split()[1])
        if current_pid != pid:
            try:
                os.kill(current_pid, signal.SIGSTOP)
                print("Killed: ", proc)
            except:
                print("Couldn't kill: ", proc)
```

If you did want to use the script name, you can also do that dynamically:

```
from pathlib import Path
script_name = Path(__file__).name
```